# Проигрывание видео при наведении курсора WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html5

Подскажите, как сделать на WordPress,что бы при наведении курсора мыши вместо статической картинки,проигрывалось видео?[image: Вот Здесь]

Answer (score 1):

Тег `video` управляется с помощью js.

**myVideo.play()** - проигрывается видео.

**myVideo.pause()** - останавливается видео.

**mov_bbb.mp4** - ссылка на видео

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video width="400" id='video1'>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


<script>
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 

myVideo.onmouseover = function(){
 myVideo.play(); 
};

myVideo.onmouseout = function(){
 myVideo.pause(); 
};
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```